# FILESTREAM access via streaming API

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, filestream

On a web server, we plan to pull back a file stored in SQL in a FILESTREAM using the Win32 streaming API.  Are there any special ports that must be opened to make this work?  Or will the standard 1433 suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**documentation**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx):

> Remote file system access to `FILESTREAM` data is enabled over the `Server Message Block (SMB)` protocol.

If you want to use the streaming `API`, you'll need to open `SMB` access to your web server from the outside: probably not a best idea if the web server is public.